# jQuery selectors: select two elements, and all elements in between

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a load of LIs inside an UL, and each one has a unique ID.

Given two IDs, what's the best way to select the two corresponding LIs, *and* all the LIs in between?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

> Given a selector expression that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.nextUntil()` method searches through the successors of these elements in the DOM tree, stopping when it reaches an element matched by the method's argument. The new jQuery object that is returned contains all following siblings up to but not including the one matched by the `.nextUntil()` argument.
>
> If the selector is not matched or is not supplied, all following siblings will be selected; in these cases it selects the same elements as the `.nextAll()` method does when no filter selector is provided.
>
> **As of jQuery 1.6**, A DOM node or jQuery object, instead of a selector, may be passed to the `.nextUntil()` method.
>
> The method optionally accepts a selector expression for its second argument. If this argument is supplied, the elements will be filtered by testing whether they match it...

Comment: nextUntil does not consider the first and last elements as OP requires.

Answer (score 50):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#id').nextUntil('#id2').andSelf().add('#id2')
```

It's important to note that [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) does **not** include the element it's going until, it stops with the one before it.  To add that element, you need to call [`.add(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) on the end.

You also need a [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) to include the *first* element

**Update August 2017**

jQuery method [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) is now deprecated in jQuery 1.8+, use [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) instead to add the first selection back. Also,[`.prevUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) can be used if last element (#id2) percedes the first element (#id1) in the selection. Compare[`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for both elements to determine their order in the document.

Comment: @jAndy - `.addSelf()` would include the original ID, not the ending element, you still need `.add()` for the ending ID

Comment: @Nick: which is exactly what he wants.

Comment: @jAndy if you have li 1, 2, 3, 4, without the `.add()`, 4 will NOT be included, `.nextUntil()` is non-inclusive.  From the docs: "The new jQuery object that is returned contains all following siblings up to but not including the one matched by the `.nextUntil()` selector."

Comment: I know, I didn't mean to append it, just to add it into the expression

Comment: @jAndy - Ah, yes in that case we're on the same page, was testing in fiddle when I realized that as well.

Comment: what me actually brings to the question, if there is a way in jQuery with that you can get the 'root' selector in a later function. That would replace the .add('#id2') into something like .add(':next') or .add(root.next()) mmmhhh!

Comment: @jAndy - It's possible, resig did a post on this a while back about a chaining porposal: http://ejohn.org/blog/ultra-chaining-with-jquery/ If you combined with using the `$(...).selector` property you could use it in the chain, but it'd be pretty hard to follow if it got deep :)

Comment: This will only work when #id comes before #id2. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19046986/219931)

Comment: @Dziamid you can actually do that much cheaper since .add() maintains document order, so you can .add() and .slice() to do it in 2 lines and much less CPU...if you're unsure of the order going in.

Answer (score -8):

To select the All LIs in Between UL

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("li[ID*=ids]").css("bacground-color","red");// contian common world ex ids1
    });
```

Comment: This would select all `<li>` with an `id` containing `ids`...this doesn't at all answer the question.

Comment: Not my downvote, but based on other answers this morning I've seen...you need to read the questions a bit better, an off-topic or completely incorrect answer is rarely helpful