# Get siblings between 2 elements

Tags: jquery

How can I get the elements between 2 other elements?

Like if I had:

```
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c2"></div>
<div class="c3"></div>
<div class="c4"></div>
<div class="c5"></div>
<div class="c6"></div>
<div class="c7"></div>
```

I want to get the elements between `div.c3` and `div.c6`.

Comment: Including or excluding `div.c3` and `div.c6`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With [`nextUntil` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
var $siblings = $('.c3').nextUntil('.c6');
```

Comment: Won't let me mark your answer as correct for another 7 minutes (so you know where the delay is from).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to first check if elements come in the proper order, othenwise nextUntil will return unexpected set of elements.

```
/**
 * Returns an array of sibling elements between `from` and `to` including `from` and `to`
 */
function getElementsInBetween (from, to) {
        var range = [];

        if (from.index() > to.index()) { //ensure that 'from' is before 'to'
            from = [to, to = from][0]; //swapping from and to
        }

        if (from.is(to)) {
            range = [from];
        } else {
            range = from.nextUntil(to).add(from).add(to);
            range = $.makeArray(range);
        }

        return range;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If its only for styling purposes, and you don't want to use a Script, you can do it that way..

lets say that you want to style the elements between `.c3` and `.c6`

```
.c3 ~ div
{
    /*special styling*/
}
div, .c6 ~ div
{
    /*normal styling*/
}
```

you can see it in action [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/a3c72/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following:

```
var selected_elems = $("div").slice(2,6);
```

`slice()`: reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: Nice approach. [extra chars]

Comment: Works well if you have a known list of elements, but not really useful for dynamically generated lists.