# Retrieve Html datas between two div with same classes with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

How could I retrieve HTML datas between two div having the same class but with no children like here:

```
<div class="scene"> EXT.PARK.DAY </div>
<div class="action"> He is walking fast.</div>
<div class="character">JOHN</div>
<div class="dialog">I have to hurry!</div>
<div class="scene">INT.WAITING ROOM.DAY</div>
```

As an example the result of the query to retrieve everything between the div with scene class would be to retrieve all this:

```
<div class="action"> He is walking fast.</div>
<div class="character">JOHN</div>
<div class="dialog">I have to hurry!</div>
```

How could get these elements with Jquery ?

Comment: what have your tried so far ? Please share your code

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery selectors: select two elements, and all elements in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698259/jquery-selectors-select-two-elements-and-all-elements-in-between)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/)

```js
$(".scene")
  .nextUntil(".scene")
  .css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="scene"> EXT.PARK.DAY </div>
<div class="action"> He is walking fast.</div>
<div class="character">JOHN</div>
<div class="dialog">I have to hurry!</div>
<div class="scene">INT.WAITING ROOM.DAY</div>
```

Comment: This solution won't work if you put any element after second scene class div.

Comment: Would you know how one can achieve the same thing with cheerio js ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply some css to the element between scene class then see below soltion.

```js
var childs = document.body.children;
for(var i = $('.scene').index() + 1; i < childs.length; i++) {
    if($(childs[i]).hasClass('scene')){
      break;
    }
    $(childs[i]).css('color', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scene"> EXT.PARK.DAY </div>
<div class="action"> He is walking fast.</div>
<div class="character">JOHN</div>
<div class="dialog">I have to hurry!</div>
<div class="scene">INT.WAITING ROOM.DAY</div>
```

And if you want to get element between scene class div and put it in another div then you use below code.

```js
function extract() {
  var childs = document.body.children;
  var extracted_elements = '';
  for (var i = $('.scene').index() + 1; i < childs.length; i++) {
    if ($(childs[i]).hasClass('scene')) {
      break;
    }
    
    extracted_elements += $(childs[i])[0].outerHTML;
  }
  $('.extracted_elements').html(extracted_elements);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scene"> EXT.PARK.DAY </div>
<div class="action"> He is walking fast.</div>
<div class="character">JOHN</div>
<div class="dialog">I have to hurry!</div>
<div class="scene">INT.WAITING ROOM.DAY</div>
<br />
<button onclick="extract()">Extract</button>
<hr>
<div class="extracted_elements">
</div>
```